# prettify-symbols-mode not working in auctex

Tags: latex, auctex, prettify-symbols-mode

In my `.emacs` file, I have `(global-prettify-symbols-mode)`, and if I visit a `.el` document, I see the lambda character instead of `lambda`.

My understanding is that in a `.tex` file I should see the beta character instead of `\beta`, but this does not seem to work. The auctex manual says that if global prettify symbols mode is enabled, then this should work automatically.

Any ideas of what could be going wrong?

Comment: Is `prettify-symbols-mode` enabled in your `.tex` file?

Comment: Yes, it is. And I've tried disabling it and then re-enabling it.

Comment: Are you using Emacs 25? Apparently there were problems in 24 with prettify https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2016-03/msg00040.html

Comment: Yes, on Arch Linux (if it makes a difference)

Comment: I've just checked and you are right.  When I disable and re-enable `prettify-symbols-mode` in my LaTeX buffer, the prettification works.  Strangely, with the dev version of GNU AUCTeX, the prettification is there immediately when finding a new TeX file.  But there are no changes at all wrt prettification between 11.89.5 and the dev version.

Not sure what's the problem...

Comment: My problem was fixed by disabling company-auctex.

Comment: This problem seems to be still happening with Emacs 25.1 and auctex-11.89.7. In my case, it only happens for certain document classes (such as "amsart", "beamer", but not "article"). Other font-lock customization added through TeX-mode-hook also tends to get lost in these document classes and only in them. If anyone wants to reproduce this, remember to set TeX-parse-self to t.